# Six-words (------||||||)

Tags: word, wordplay, crosswords, word-square

My 1st go at this (and first post here). I hope you like.

> 1. This puzzle is degrading.
> 2. There are plants (with ain)
> 3. And the clues are quite obtuse.
> 4. It is a smelly, meaty extrude of a puzzle:
> 5. My excrement flowing out of me.
> 6. I take pleasure in your suffering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> ```
> A B A S E S
> B A N A N A
> A N G L E D
> S A L A M I
> E N E M A S
> S A D I S T
> ```

I think the only ones that require particular explanation are:

> BANANA - As per explanation from rand al'thor, a banana looks a bit like a plant-ain

and

> ANGLED - As in obtuse angle

Comment: Well done Pete. Exactly right.

Comment: Nice job! Note "sadism" would also work for the last line...

Answer (score 1):

*2. There are plants (with ain)*

> Plantain looks a bit like banana, so I'll say BANANA for this one.

*4. It is a smelly, meaty extrude of a puzzle:

5. My excrement flowing out of me.*

> One of these is probably MANURE. If the second clue is BANANA, then it must be the fourth and not the fifth that's MANURE.

*1. This puzzle is degrading.*

> Given 2 and 4, this could now be OBAMAS ("we will *degrade* and ultimately destroy...")

*3. And the clues are quite obtuse.

6. I take pleasure in your suffering*

> Still not sure about these.

Comment: Only one of those is correct.

Comment: @Avon BANANA or MANURE? Or would that be giving away too much? :-)

Comment: It would be a spoiler in a comment. I would think 4 and 5 are probably the hardest to get so I would leave them to last.